# filepicker.makeDropPane and the FPFile "key" attribute

Tags: filepicker.io

According to the filepicker web docs, `filepicker.pick` will no longer return `key` as an attribute of the FPFiles passed to the onSuccess callback.

Since `filepicker.pick` seems like the most general-case api call, it seems like it would be representational of how other api calls might be changing going forward.

This makes me wonder if the `FPFiles` passed to the `onSuccess` callback in `filepicker.makeDropPane` will also no longer be getting a `key` attribute.  The documentation makes no note about it in the `filepicker.makeDropPane` area.

There is also nothing in the docs that says whether backing up your images to S3 is an option that you can specify when using `filepicker.makeDropPane`.  I actually do want this to happen, and it's working fine, but I'm not specifying any boolean parameter that says filepicker should do this for me.  This makes me worry that at some point filepicker may change the default behavior under the hood, breaking my application without warning.

The documentation for `filepicker.pick` states:

> Note: the "key" parameter is deprecated and will be removed soon. If
>   you want to store files immediately after picking, use the
>   filepicker.pickAndStore call.

Well, that's good to know about `filepicker.pick`, but what about `filepicker.makeDropPane`?  Is there a planned `filepicker.makeDropPaneAndStore`?  Will there be some other way to specify automatic upload to S3?  Will `filepicker.makeDropPane` forever upload to S3 automatically, for no specified reason?  Or should we treat `filepicker.makeDropPane` like `filepicker.pick`, and assume it doesn't upload to S3, and call `filepicker.pickAndStore` for each `FPFile` after they're uploaded?  If so, when should we make that change, because right now it'd be redundant since it's already uploading to S3 automatically, and we'd be duplicating each S3 upload?

In addition to these questions, currently the `FPFiles` being passed to the `onSuccess` callback of `filepicker.makeDropPane` have an undocumented `id` attribute.  This `id` attribute isn't unique - it's the same for every `FPFile`. Will this change to being unique?  Should we avoid using this?  Why's it there if it's not documented?

Which `FPFile` attribute should we use for actually keeping track of `FPFiles` locally?  `url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in interpreting that the makeDropPane needs a more explicit declaration of where to store the uploads - to "future-proof" your implementation, I'd recommend adding a `{store_location: "S3"}` as an option, which will signal to us that the upload should be stored into your S3 (as opposed to rackspace, etc.), and will guaranteeing that we return a `key`.

Regarding the `id` attribute, I'm not seeing this behavior, if you have any more specifics (or a jsfiddle, etc) that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will add that.  Sorry about the `id` misunderstanding - it looks like it was probably my code adding that.